# Windows 7 gray screen

Tags: windows-7, windows

Mother was using my hp pavilion g6 laptop and she said it froze. She was able to turn it off "finally" and turn it back on. It looks like it is starting windows but the windows logo never shows and then it comes to a gray screen. It's gray with light lines, looks like a curtain. I can't do anything from here except for move the mouse. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a lot like Startup Recovery. Does your HP Laptop have its own recovery partition that you can boot from and reinstall Windows?

Comment: This appears to be a comment instead of an answer

Comment: Finally, startup recovery started running, but it's been running for over 2 hours, "attempting to repair". I guess we'll see what happens. I do not want to reinstall because I do not want to lose anything that I haven't backed up.